# Can I make only certain C# classes COM-exposed?

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a C# library project which is designed to be used from unmanaged C++ code via COM.
[image]

Only 2 or 3 methods are going to be called in this way but I get warnings like this:

> warning : Type library exporter warning processing ''.
>   Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type instance in
>   a signature. Generic code may not be exported to COM.

These properties and methods are not designed to be accessed from C++, an in fact they are not even `public` methods so they (surely) wouldn't be visible anyway.

Two questions really:

- **Q1: How can I control what is exported? Access modifiers on classes/methods or something else?**
- **Q2: How can I see what is exported e.g. check what's in the type library to see if I missed something**

It would be nice to double check I'm not bloating my type-library with a load of stuff that's not supposed to be there...

Comment: The assembly should have ComVisible(false) so it's the default value, and then put ComVisible(true) on "things" (classes, methods, etc.) you want to export. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute To check what's in a .tlb, use OleView from Windows SDK

Comment: @SimonMourier is the checkbox above still supposed to be checked if _anything_ should be COM-visible, is that controlling the `ComVisible` status of the assembly? Otherwise I'm not sure where I apply it on the assembly itself. BTW this basically is the answer to my quesiton, I think, if you care to write it as an answer

Comment: The "register for COM Interop" is about registration (regasm), it not strictly related to what's exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can declare the whole assembly to be invisible to COM, like this (in fact when you use Visual Studio C# class library template it should put it itself in AssemblyInfo.cs):

```
// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

Now, in each class I can decide it will be visible to COM or not like here:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [ProgId("MyCoolClass")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class MyCoolVisibleClass
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello COM world");
        }

        // explicit non COM visible because it's set to true at class level
        [ComVisible(false)]
        public void SayHello2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        }
    }

    // implicit non COM visible
    public class MyCoolInvisibleClass
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the project properties to register ("Register for COM Interop" checkbox) , but I personally register myself with a command line like this (for 64-bit registry world):

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe ClassLibrary1.dll /codebase /tlb
```

This outputs something like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe ClassLibrary1.dll /codebase /tlb
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.8.3752.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.3752.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it.
Types registered successfully
Assembly exported to 'D:\KilroyWasHere\ClassLibrary1.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully
```

And I can check what's really inside the .tlb using [OleView from Windows SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer):

[image]